# Error in R: The subscript var has the wrong type quosure/formula. It must be numeric or character

Tags: r, error-handling, dataset, geospatial, data-cleaning

**Code:**

```
GeoSeparate <- function(Dataset, GeoColumn) {
  GeoColumn <- enquo(GeoColumn) 
  Dataset %>% 
    separate(GeoColumn, into = c("Section1", "Section2"), sep = "\\(")%>%
    separate(Section1, into = c("Section3", "Section4"), sep = ",")%>%
    separate(Section2, into = c("GeoColumn", "Section5"), sep = "\\)")%>%
    separate(GeoColumn, into = c("GeoColumnLat", "GeoColumnLon"), sep = ",")%>%
    select(-Section3, -Section4, -Section5) #remove sections we don't need
}
```

**Test:**

```
GeoSeparate(df3, DeathCityGeo)
```

**Error:**

`Must extract column with a single subscript.
x The subscript`var`has the wrong type`quosure/formula`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.`

My function separates a column that has the format: "Norwalk, CT\n(41.11805, -73.412906)" so that the latitude and longitude are all that remain and they are in two separate columns. It worked for a while, but now I get the error message described above. It may be because I updated my libraries but I'm not sure. Any help would be amazing! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to evaluate (`!!`)

```
GeoSeparate <- function(Dataset, GeoColumn) {
    GeoColumn <- enquo(GeoColumn) 
    Dataset %>% 
        separate(!!GeoColumn, into = c("Section1", "Section2"), sep = "\\(")%>%
        separate(Section1, into = c("Section3", "Section4"), sep = ",")%>%
        separate(Section2, into = c("GeoColumn", "Section5"), sep = "\\)")%>%
        separate(!!GeoColumn, into = c("GeoColumnLat", "GeoColumnLon"), sep = ",")%>%
        select(-Section3, -Section4, -Section5) #remove sections we don't need
    }
```

---

Or another option is `curly-curly` (`{{}}`)

```
GeoSeparate <- function(Dataset, GeoColumn) {

        Dataset %>% 
            separate({{GeoColumn}}, into = c("Section1", "Section2"), sep = "\\(")%>%
            separate(Section1, into = c("Section3", "Section4"), sep = ",")%>%
            separate(Section2, into = c("GeoColumn", "Section5"), sep = "\\)")%>%
            separate({{GeoColumn}}, into = c("GeoColumnLat", "GeoColumnLon"), sep = ",")%>%
            select(-Section3, -Section4, -Section5) #remove sections we don't need
        }
```

Comment: thank you -- I tried that and now it says "Error: object 'DeathCityGeo' not found." Do you know why that may be?

Comment: @ajg I can't reproduce the issue.  Can you test on this `f1 <- function(dat, col1) separate(dat, {{col1}}, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep=4);
f1(head(iris), Species)`

Comment: I'm not sure. Still trying to figure it out. I've tested the common errors for object not found but haven't fixed the issue. @akrun

Comment: @ajg Is the column name correct i.e. it should work with correct name as I showed in the 'f1'

Comment: Just fixed it! I realized the second "GeoColumn" in my function was created in my separate function and therefore should not be in {{}} but I've changed it to NewGeoColumn so I don't get confused next time. Thanks for your help @akrun